# How to register a class with generic type param using injectable?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc, injectable

I have a bloc, that I want to register for DI:

```
@injectable
class ViewBloc<T> extends Bloc<ViewEvent, ViewState> { }
```

As you can see the **ViewBloc** takes a generic type param **T**. The problem is that when the injectable register the dependency, it's doing it wrong:

```
gh.factory<ViewBloc<dynamic>>(() => ViewBloc<dynamic>();
```

It's being given a dynamic type param by default, but I want to be able to provide the type myself. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score -3):

from the [Injectable docs](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable#binding-abstract-classes-to-implementations)

> Use the 'as' Property inside of Injectable(as:..) to pass an abstract type
> that's implemented by the registered dependency

```dart
@Injectable(as: Service)  
class ServiceImpl implements Service {}  
  
// or  
@Singleton(as: Service)  
class ServiceImpl implements Service {}  
  
// or  
@LazySingleton(as: Service)  
class ServiceImpl implements Service {}
```

Comment: My problem is regarding passing a generic type parameter.